Inner products which are not a dot product, and the impact on orthogonality.
I understand that inner product is a generalization of dot product. However, what does an inner product defined as <u,v> = uTAv means, where A is a matrix? Does it means that we change the bases of both u and v to a new one to compute the inner product?
Furthermore, it is obvious that the change of inner products affect the orthogonality of the vectors, but I am struggling to understand the notion. Following the question in the first paragraph, if we define matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$:
$$<\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}> = \begin{bmatrix}1~1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix} = -1 \ne 0$$
which means the two vectors are not orthogonal (it should be if we are using dot product). Is there any great people can help me to understand this?

Recall that in an abstract vector space, there is no natural concept of orthogonality; the closest concept is that of linear independence.
For orthogonality, we require an inner product (which induces a norm $\lVert \boldsymbol{v} \rVert^2 := \langle \boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{v} \rangle$). Hence, different inner products give us different definitions of angles and lengths in the vector space. To employ a metaphor, we have changed the size of our rulers.
Taking the inner product defined by the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ you've provided above, we can see that your basis vectors are of 'lengths' (norms)
$$\lVert\boldsymbol{b}_1\rVert^2 = \langle\boldsymbol{b}_1,\boldsymbol{b}_1\rangle = \boldsymbol{b}_1{}^\intercal\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{e}_1 \quad \implies \quad \lVert\boldsymbol{b}_1\rVert = \sqrt{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}} = \sqrt{2}\,\text{,}\\
\lVert\boldsymbol{b}_2\rVert^2 = \langle\boldsymbol{b}_2,\boldsymbol{b}_2\rangle = \boldsymbol{b}_2{}^\intercal\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{b}_2 \quad \implies \quad \lVert\boldsymbol{b}_2\rVert = \sqrt{\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}} = 1\,\text{.}$$
Thus, if we wanted to change our point of view, we could adopt the orthonormal basis (according to this inner product) $E :=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\boldsymbol{b}_1, \boldsymbol{b}_2\}$. In this basis, we have
$$[\mathbf{A}]_E = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\,\text{;}$$
which is to say that the inner product becomes a dot product. And in this basis, it is clear that your vectors are non-orthogonal:
$$[\boldsymbol{u}]_E = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad[\boldsymbol{v}]_E = \begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt{2}\\1\end{bmatrix}\,\text{.}$$
TL;DR: We measure orthogonality using the 'ruler' of the inner product. Changing our ruler changes the measurements we get.
